# how to show that $1/(1+x^2)$ is a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $1/(1+x^2)$ is a contraction but I cannot find the contraction factor. So far I got: $\lvert \frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+y^2}\rvert=\lvert\frac{x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\rvert=\lvert\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\rvert$. So I got x-y in the numerator, but how do I find a bound and get rid of al the other terms?

Comment: Have you tried just bounding the derivative of $1/(1+x^2)$? You can use $2x\leq 1+x^2$.

Answer (score 4):

By the definition of the contraction map, we just prove the inequality $\vert \frac{x+y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)} \vert \leq c < 1$.
Noting that $\vert x+y \vert \leq \vert x \vert +\vert y \vert$ ,we turn to prove $\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert \leq c(1+x^2)(1+y^2)$.
Expanding and simplifying it, we have an inequality $0 \leq (\vert x\vert-\frac{1}{2c})^2+(\vert y\vert-\frac{1}{2c})^2+x^2y^2+1-\frac{1}{2c^2}$ where $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \leq c <1$, which holds obviously. So we accomplish our goal.

---

There is a gap in the old answer.
We want to prove  the inequality $\vert \frac{x+y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)} \vert <1$.
Noting that $\vert x+y \vert \leq \vert x \vert +\vert y \vert$ ,we turn to prove $\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert <(1+x^2)(1+y^2)$.
Expanding and simplifying it, we have an inequality $0<(\vert x\vert-\frac{1}{2})^2+(\vert y\vert-\frac{1}{2})^2+x^2y^2+\frac{1}{2}$ which holds obviously. So we accomplish our goal.

Comment: Proving that the first inequality is less than one is not enough. To be a contraction the inequality needs to be way of $1$ uniformly.

Comment: @OliverDiaz indeed, but it vanishes as $|(x,y)|\to \infty$ so extreme value theorem gives that it is $\le c < 1$

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Agree, but the answer does not make that connection.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, CalvinKhor, yeah, yeah, it's my falut, I'll fix it.